# How to read serial port with custom baudrates?

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, rust-cargo

I am using rust for reading serial port. I need to read it with baudrate = 100000. I tried a library called [rppal](https://github.com/golemparts/rppal).

I used examples of library to read and I got `InvalidValue` error.

```rust
extern crate rppal;

use rppal::uart::{Parity, Uart};

use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut uart =
        Uart::with_path("/dev/ttyS1", 10000, Parity::Even, 8, 2).expect("COULD SET UART");
    uart.set_read_mode(1, Duration::default())
        .expect("COULD SET UART MODE");

    let buffer = [0u8; 8];
    loop {
        // Fill the buffer variable with any incoming data.

        for i in 0..7 {
            println!("Received byte: {}", buffer[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
Running `target/debug/readuart`
thread 'main' panicked at 'COULD SET UART: InvalidValue', src/main.rs:11:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "readuart"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [" <sahsxxxxx@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

rppal = "0.11.3"
```

I run project using:

```bash
cargo run
```

Also is not a hardware issue because pyserial can read values correctly with correct baudrates.

Comment: HI Alex, could you please try to start your program with root privileges?

Comment: error is changed

Comment: 10000 is not a standard baud rates, try to use a baud rates which is multiples of 4800 like 9600,14400,19200,38400?

Comment: the sbus protocol is working on 10000  . What about using the dividers ir is not posssible.